# How to debug a database error of "Incorrect syntax near the keyword X"?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to count the number of user so that I can generate the unique id for new user. But the query which I have written shows some syntax error near User where User is my Table name.

```
private int GenerateAutoId()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Count(*) from User",con);
    var temp = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
    con.Close();
    i=i+1;
    return i;
}
```

Error Message:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action'1 wrapCloseInAction) +2555926
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action'1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +5959200    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4169
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +58
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +89
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean
>   shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) +430
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2598
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +1483
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) +64
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +240
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() +99
>   SignUpPage_SignUp.GenerateAutoId() in
>   d:\SEM-4\WT\ProjectStayHealthy\StayHealthy\templates.aucreative.co\Project\SignUpPage\SignUp.aspx.cs:22
>   SignUpPage_SignUp.SignUp_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   d:\SEM-4\WT\ProjectStayHealthy\StayHealthy\templates.aucreative.co\Project\SignUpPage\SignUp.aspx.cs:31
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9782698
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +204
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +12
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1639

Comment: why do you generate you own "auto id" when you can have the database do it for you?

Comment: The SQL Server can have more than one database.  The default database my be different from the you code which doesn't have a User Table.  The database may not be working so I would use SQL Server Management Studio and check if database is working.

Comment: @jdweng: That wouldn't cause the error message the OP is seeing.

Comment: When creating objects, using aliases, etc, you should really avoid the use of [Reserved Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You have to quote them otherwise, and code that doesn't quote them will not work.

Comment: @Progman is right. What you're doing here seems like really you should be using an `IDENTITY` column. The solution doesn't even stop reuse of an `ID`. Say you have 10 Users (ID's 1-10), then delete User 7. You then try to create a new user, you now have another User with the ID 10.

Answer (score 2):

The hint is in the error message, but you do need to read it carefully:

> Incorrect syntax near the **keyword** 'User'

`User` is a [reserved word in T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) so you need to escape it in your query:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Count(*) from [User]", con))
{
    // Note: avoid converting to and from strings unnecessarily.
    return (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

(Alternatively, change the table name to a non-reserved word if you can, of course...)

The `using` statement is to dispose of the command after you've finished using it - it's not the cause of the problem you're seeing, but it's still a good idea. It looks like you also have a single connection which you're repeatedly opening and closing. It's generally a better idea to create a new `SqlConnection` on each call and again use a `using` statement to close it... let the connection pooling infrastructure make sure that's efficient.

As noted in comments, using the count of a table isn't a good idea for generating IDs, either. Let the database do that for you.

Comment: @Jon Skeet...I find I have to consult the thesauruses more and more these days.